# "invalid use of void expression"

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need to write a macro that operates on bitarray looking like this:

```
   array[0] = number of bits in bitarray (integer) 
   array[1..n] = bits
```

Macro must look like:

```
GetBit(pointer, index)
Macro *must* return 0,1 or call function similar to exit().
```

This is my (working) inline-function version of macro that I'm supposed to write:

```
static inline unsigned long GetBit(BitArray_t array, unsigned long index)
{
        if ((index) >= array[0])
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        else
                return (GetBit_wo_boundary_checks(array,index));
}
```

This is what I've got:

```
#define GetBit(array,index)\
                (((index) < array[0] || exit(EXIT_FAILURE)) ?\
                        GetBit_wo_boundary_checks(array,index) : 0)
```

My problem is that this *has* to do index boundary check (i < p[0]) and exit before it tries to access undefined memory with GetBit_wo_boundary_checks(p,i).

I thought that I could work around this by putting exit into short-circuit evaluated condition, but I get: **"invalid use of void expression"**.

Is there any way to make this expression macro transparently exit() when index is higher than maximum defined in array[0]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use the comma operator with your `exit()` call, like:

```
(exit(EXIT_FAILURE), 0)
```

It's a little hack-ish, but this will make the expression return the value `0` and should satisfy the compiler.

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried it before and it didn't work, but this time compiler does not complain. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `,` operator to do this:

```
#define GetBit(array,index) \
            (((index) >= array[0]) \
             ? exit(EXIT_FAILURE), -1 \
             : GetBit_wo_boundary_checks(array,(index)))
```

Note that `index` is evaluated twice, which is not safe.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing your `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` with `(exit(EXIT_FAILURE), 1)`? Though it's only a guess, that should do the trick. The expression now produces a value (the right operand of the comma operator -- 1, in this case) but forces evaluation of the call to `exit` first, which is the part you really care about.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could declare a function "similar to exit" which calls exit and returns a value.